# Materialize toast is rendering empty JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, toast

I'm working with Materialize (latest version) and trying to create Toast with a button, they show up but are empty!

Here is the code, and a codepen link: https://codepen.io/jvelezr/pen/xxZvqEP

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button-action").on("click", function() {
        
            toastContent = 'This is a test + &nbsp;<span><button class="btn-flat toast-action">DESHACER</button></span>';
            M.toast(toastContent, 15000);
          });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Materialize Toast documentation](https://materializecss.com/toasts.html), the function accepts an options object with `html` and `displayLength` properties. So your example should look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button-action").on("click", function() {
    const toastOptions = {
      html: 'This is a test + &nbsp;<span><button class="btn-flat toast-action">DESHACER</button></span>',
      displayLength: 15000
    };
    M.toast(toastOptions);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" id="button-action">Test Me!</div>
```